# (amCharts) I have a chart which data has two different prefixes. Any way to tell the function which data has which prefix?

Tags: javascript, jquery, amcharts

I have an amChart chart which data is taken from two tables below it (code is modified [from this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46791163/651170)). Every row the category in each tables begins with different prefix: first table begins with **(Sales)** and second table begins with **(Market)**.

Here is my code for better illustration: http://jsfiddle.net/uoxbm2d3/2/

Since there are two tables and it's a column/bar chart, I need the columns/bars to be stacked based on from which table or what prefix they have. So (Sales) will only be stacked with (Sales) or, in other words, data from Table 1 will only be stacked with Table 1. Same goes with (Market)/Table 2 that will only be stacked with its siblings. Something like this:

[image: Sorry for the terrible editing, but you get the idea]

The green/yellow/orange color is from Table 1 (Sales); the blue/purple color is from Table 2 (Market).

Is there any way to tell the function which graph comes from which table? Or at least to tell the function which data has which prefix?

Here is a piece of the script

```js
    function generateGraphsFromData(chart, chartData) {
    //get the chart graph value fields as lookup table with a seen property set to false by default
    //this will be used to determine what graphs need to be removed when looking at the data
    var graphValueFields = chart.graphs.reduce(function(valueFields, graph) {
        valueFields[graph.valueField] = 0;
        return valueFields;
    }, {});

    var removeValueFields = [];

    //create an array of new graph value fields by filtering out the categoryField
    //and the currently known valueFields. 
    var newGraphValueFields = [];

    Object.keys(chartData[0]).filter(function(key) {
        return key != chart.categoryField;
    }).forEach(function(valueField) {
        //if this is a new graph, add it to the list
        if (graphValueFields[valueField] === undefined) {
            newGraphValueFields.push(valueField);
        } else {
            //otherwise, set the seen flag to 1
            graphValueFields[valueField] = 1;
        }
    });

    //for each new value field left over, create a graph object and add to the chart.
    newGraphValueFields.forEach(function(valueField) {
        var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
        graph.title = valueField;
        graph.valueField = valueField;
        graph.balloonText = "<strong>[[title]]</strong><br /> Rp[[value]]";
        graph.id = valueField; //use the valueField as the ID for ease of removal
        graph.type = 'column';
        graph.lineAlpha = 0;
        graph.fillAlphas = 0.5;
        graph.bullet = "none";
        graph.stackable = true; // disable stacking
        chart.addGraph(graph);
    });

    //loop through the graphValueFields lookup table and remove all graphs that were not seen when
    //rescanning the data
    Object.keys(graphValueFields).forEach(function(removeGraphValueField) {
        if (graphValueFields[removeGraphValueField] === 0) {
            chart.removeGraph(chart.getGraphById(removeGraphValueField));
        }
    })
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you add your new graphs and remove any old ones, you can sort by title then loop through them again to find the first non-matching prefix and set the graph's [`newStack`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#newStack) property to true while setting it to false in the rest of the graphs. For example:

```
  chart.graphs.sort(function(lhs, rhs) {
    //sort by title, ensures that the sales (first table) data comes first
    var lhsSalesIdx = lhs.title.indexOf('(Sales)');
    var rhsSalesIdx = rhs.title.indexOf('(Sales)');

    if (lhsSalesIdx !== -1 && rhsSalesIdx === -1) {
      return -1;
    }
    else if (lhsSalesIdx === -1 && rhsSalesIdx !== -1) {
      return 1;
    }
    else {
        return lhs.title.localeCompare(rhs.title);
    }
  });
  var stackSet = false;
  //find the first instance of the market row graph and set its newStack property to true
  //while clearing out the others
    for (var i = 0; i < chart.graphs.length; ++i) {
    if (!stackSet && chart.graphs[i].title.indexOf('(Sales)') === -1) {
        chart.graphs[i].newStack = true;
        stackSet = true;
    }
    else {
      chart.graphs[i].newStack = false;
    }     
  }
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uoxbm2d3/3/) - note that I set `stackable` back to true in your new graph loop for this to work as well.